# Preg_replace image inner style

Tags: php, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

For a website I have strings without knowing what text or image lines there will be in them.
I want to create a replacement for the image inner style. The whole `style=""` must be removed
without knowing what styles will be between `""`.

What is the pattern for the replace I need.

Comment: I wanted just to know what pattern I need to use to get this work :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use a regular expression for this, since an HTML parser will be much more robust.  If the style attribute is always going to be similar, with just minor variations, then you can use the following to change it:

```
$yourStyle = 'style="your-style-goes-here"';
$newString = preg_replace('%style="(.*?)"%is', $yourStyle, $string);
```

If you just want to remove the style attribute completely, then set `$yourStyle = '';`

Again, this is not the best way to do this, but it will work assuming that you never have a quotation mark in the middle of the style and that the style attribute ends with a quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help:

```
$data = array(
    '<img src="hello/test.png" />',
    '<img src="hello/test.png"/>',
    '<img src="hello/test.png">',
    '<img src="mama" style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" border="0" />',
    '<img src="mama" style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" border="0"/>',
    '<img src="mama" style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" border="0">',
    '<img src="mama" style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" />',
    '<img src="mama" style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black"/>',
    '<img src="mama" style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black">',
    '<img style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" src="mama" />',
    '<img style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" src="mama"/>',
    '<img style="blabla; background-color: #98473; border: 1px solid black" src="mama">',
);
foreach($data as $texttosearch){
    echo htmlentities($texttosearch).' => '.htmlentities(preg_replace('/(<img .*?)(style=("|\').*?("|\'))(.*?(\/?)>)/i', '$1$5', $texttosearch)).'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
/(?:style=")(?:[\w\-\:\;\s\%\#]+)(?:\")/i
```

It will strip majority of style attributes from any tag. You can place it in a function and feed it the parts you want to check/replace